# What exactly is #^:_1

Tags: j

So I came across this bit of code on the j website:

```
mask #!.fill^:_1 lst
```

where mask is a bit list.

Makes sense as far as it goes. The result is the obverse of mask&#, applied to lst, with the unknown values replaced with fill.

However, it doesn't seem to generalize:

```
2 2 (#!._^:_1) 3 3 4 4
```

yields a domain error, rather than "3 4", as you might expect.

What exactly is #^:_1, and why isn't it a proper obverse of #?

Comment: Obverses are listed in the [page for power](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm): `b&#^:_1 where b is a boolean list is Expand (whose fill atom f can be specified by fit, b&#^:_1!.f or #^:_1!.f )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe `(#!._^:_1)` spreads out the right argument by either taking the indexed value if the position has a one or filling in with the fill value if it is a zero.

```
   (1 1 0 1 0 1)   (#!._^:_1) 3 3 4 4
3 3 _ 4 _ 4
```

It doesn't generalize completely because values other 1 or 0 will result in the domain error that you see. See case 6 on this dictionary page. http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm

You might also look at the way that complex numbers interact with the standard (non-obverse) version of #, as this seems more generalizable.

```
2j1   #!._ 3 3 4 4
3 3 _ 3 3 _ 4 4 _ 4 4 _
   2j1 1j2 3j0 1j1   #!._ 3 3 4 4
3 3 _ 3 _ _ 4 4 4 4 _
```

In this case the real component of the complex argument `mjn` makes `m` copies of the corresponding right item and the imaginary component inserts `n` fill values.
http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d400.htm

Comment: Yeah it was right there on the dictionary page. Thanks guys! It is kinda weird - _expand_ is the special case of what _would_ be a true obverse of #. Wonder why it wasn't implemented in full. Not useful?